# Wordpress Autoptimize plugin error on IE and Edge browser

Tags: wordpress, caching, optimization

I have website on WordPress: https://cybeready.com/blog/ and I'm using Autoptimize and WP super cache plugins. When I check Optimise CSS Code option, the website is blank (looks like blog page), when I uncheck this, the website looks normal (like any other pages). How can I repair this? I excluded jquery from optimization.

Comment: Looks fine to me on Edge so I'm guessing you disabled the Optimize CSS option. If that's the case we won't be able to help you debug the issue so please enable it again so we can see what's going on.

Comment: please check this link https://cybeready.com/blog/

Comment: I did, and again it looks fine to me on Edge: http://oi66.tinypic.com/24ux4di.jpg

Comment: Clear your catch, you might be seeing this error due to your browser.

Comment: Thy on IE browser, please

Comment: Anyone have any idea? https://cybeready.com/ still fighting with this...